# How redux manage large data in store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux.If I have large data (100000 records) in two or more pages that all of them are editable.
Redux how manage it?

Should I load all data in store even most of those records not rendered yet?

what is exactly mean of :

> The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within a single store.
>   https://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html

Answer (score 1):

Redux provides a sane data flow. It is not about data management. Your concerns should be more or less directed to the render bit. Or in other words React. I see two problems:

- How you load so many records
- How you render them so there's no performance penalty.

The first problem may be solved using pagination while the second one by using a component like https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: should i replace store's data with new data when i go to another page ?
can you give me some sample link that have multi pages?

Comment: You don't have to do it. If you see a decrease in performance I'll suggest to implement a smart logic about clearing the bits which are not rendered and only keep a pointer about what the user sees.

Comment: can you give me some sample link that have multi pages?
all existed samples is about Todo app!!

Comment: What you mean by pages?

Comment: Multi pages applications that every page have new states and face.
for example to do app that existed on official redux site just have one page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of such tutorial or example.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a normal JavaScript object. I don't think it's feasible to keep all that data in memory. That's why databases exist after all. You have a number of solutions of course.

Comment: how should i manage it?
does redux handle it for me?
what happen if go to new page?what happen for previous page's data?